# Signalr issue with IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, signalr

I have a chat app that runs fine in windows 7 using the Visual studio integrated web server as well as in IIS 7.5

The app how ever fails to work in windows 2008 server with IIS 7.0

The hub is loading fine.. But some times the serverside fails to call the client side, no error or anything

The issue is it's very inconsistant.. same call works very rarely, fails most of the time.. Has anyone faced this?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS was set to run on multiple worker process and signalR fails in such cases.
I used [redis server to scle out signalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-with-Redis-Running-on-a-Windows-Azure-Virtual-Machine).